# Get XML node information?

Tags: xml, vba

In Excel:

I have a script that takes an address I have (in `A1`) and looks this address up via GoogleAPI, which returns an XML document.

For example, using `"123 Fake Street"` as the address returns the following XML document:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=123%20fake%20street&sensor=false

As you can see (maybe surprisingly), there's more than one `"123 fake street"` out there.  I have my macro getting the GPS coordinates from the Lat/Long nodes.  How would I grab the county of each?  I thought I could use the Node `"address_component"` but, as you can see, there is more than one such node per address:

[image]

Here's my code:

```vb
 Sub getXMLInfo()
    ' Adapted from  http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-read-data-from-xml-file/
    If Len(Cells(1, 1).Value) < 10 Then
    MsgBox ("Put an address in Cell A1!!")
    Exit Sub
    Else
     Call fnReadXMLByTags(Range("A1"))
    End If
    End Sub
```

...

```vb
Function fnReadXMLByTags(address As String) As String
    ' Part of of adapted from http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-read-data-from-xml-file/
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim mainWS As Worksheet
    Dim altAddress As String
    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set mainWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    mainWS.Range("A:A").Clear
    Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

    strAddress = address ' URLEncode(Address)
    'Assemble the query string
    strQuery = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?"
    strQuery = strQuery & "address=" & strAddress
    strQuery = strQuery & "&sensor=false"
    Debug.Print strQuery
    XMLFileName = strQuery

    oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)
    Set LatitudeNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat/text()")
    Set LongitudeNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng/text()")
    Set addressNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address/text()")
    Set countyNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[1]/long_name/text()")
    Set misc1 = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[0]/long_name/text()")

With mainWS
    .Range("A1,B1,C1").Interior.ColorIndex = 40
    .Range("A1,B1,C1").Borders.Value = 1
    .Range("A" & 1).Value = "Lookup Address: " & address
    .Range("B" & 1).Value = "Latitude"
    .Range("C" & 1).Value = "Longitude"
    .Range("D1").Value = "Total Coordinates: " & LatitudeNodes.Length

        For i = 0 To (LatitudeNodes.Length - 1)
            Title = LatitudeNodes(i).NodeValue
            Price = LongitudeNodes(i).NodeValue
            altAddress = addressNodes(i).NodeValue


        .Range("B" & i + 2).Borders.Value = 1
        .Range("C" & i + 2).Borders.Value = 1
        .Range("B" & i + 2).Value = Title
        .Range("C" & i + 2).Value = Price
        .Range("A" & i + 2).Value = altAddress
        .Range("E" & i + 2).Value = countyNodes(i).NodeValue
        .Range("F" & i + 2).Value = "component[0] = " & misc1(i).NodeValue

    Next
    'Reading the Attributes
    Set Nodes_Attribute = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/catalog/book")
    For i = 0 To (Nodes_Attribute.Length - 1)
        Attributes = Nodes_Attribute(i).getAttribute("id")
        .Range("A" & i + 2).Borders.Value = 1
        .Range("A" & i + 2).Value = Attributes
    Next

    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    'https://www.google.com/maps/place//@42.8795926,-78.8762132,16z
    .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(2, 4)).Resize(lastRow - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
         "=HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com/maps/place//@""&RC[-2]&"",""&RC[-1]&"",16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0"",""Link"")"
End With 'End the With mainWS

End Function
```

As you can see, I tried doing `"address_component[0]"` in my `misc1` node. That doesn't seem to grab the first `"address_component"`.  I am super new to XML, so I apologize for my lack of proper naming conventions (so if you know what I should look up for XML, please let me know!).

Thanks for any ideas or advice!

Edit: Here's what the result looks like when I try to get the info from:

```vb
Set misc1 = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[0]/long_name/text()")
Set misc2 = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[1]/long_name/text()")
Set misc3 = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[2]/long_name/text()")
Set misc4 = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[3]/long_name/text()")
Set misc5 = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[4]/long_name/text()")
        .Range("F" & i + 2).Value = misc1(i).NodeValue
    .Range("G" & i + 2).Value = misc2(i).NodeValue
    .Range("H" & i + 2).Value = misc3(i).NodeValue
    .Range("I" & i + 2).Value = misc4(i).NodeValue
    .Range("J" & i + 2).Value = misc5(i).NodeValue
```

[image]

So as you can see the county isn't always in the same "node" - is there a way I can account for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. If you want to access a specific node index, you have to put parentheses around the node name, then specify the index after. In your case, it would be:

```
Set misc1 = oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component)[5]/long_name/text()")
```

**Edit**:

To select the `long_name` node from the `address_component` that also has a `type` node with a value of `administrative_area_level_2`, you can use the following XPath:

```
/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type='administrative_area_level_2']/long_name
```

Comment: Aha, thank you!  Now that I can grab a specific node index, the rest of the stuff is kinda up to me, no?  Meaning, that it looks like nodeIndex 5 isn't always going to be the county...I assume there's no "XML" method/way to determine that? I figure I'd just use VB to do something like: `If the nodeIndex text does *not* have 'County", then keep looking. Else, use that index`.

Comment: Hm, I get the error `Run-time error '438' - Object doesn't support this property or method` on the line `county = countyNodes(i).NodeValue`, after I `Set countyNodes` to `Set countyNodes = oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component)[5]/long_name/text()")`

Comment: If the county is always `administrative_area_level_2` then you could search for the `address_component` that has that type and return the `long_name` from it.

Comment: I used `SelectSingleNode()`, so I'm returning a single node. There's no need for `countyNodes(index)`. You can change it back to `SelectNodes()` to return a collection of nodes, or just use `countyNodes.NodeValue` after `SelectSingleNode()`.

Comment: Thanks @Bond! What do I look up to learn how to return the long_name from the address_component? (What is the 'address_component' of the XML called? An attribute?         ...I tried this, but it doesn't work `Set countyNodes = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component/type/administrative_area_level_2/long_name/text()")`.

Comment: Or is the "long_name" called a "Child" for XML?  I'm trying to figure how to get the county, given the `type` "administrative_area_level_2", but can't quite figure out how...

Comment: See my edit, Bruce. You'll need to use the `[child-node=value]` syntax to select an `address_component` with a particular child.

Comment: Thanks a million!  ..[edited since Bond's answer below]. If i wanted to return the `long_name` for everything with `short_name` US, I would just use `.../address_component[type='US']/long_name/text()`, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Anything in `<>` is a node, so `<type>`, `<long_name>`, `<short_name>` are all _child nodes_ of `<address_component>`. To select a child node, you use `/parent/child` syntax. But you don't want the _child_ (`<type>`). You want the _parent_ that has a specific child. That's where the `[child-node=value]` syntax comes into play.